# How does Hudson work standalone on Linux?

Tags: linux, web-services, hudson

I need to know the mechanisms and flow for starting up Hudson, so I can figure out what's wrong. When you type in

```
nohup java -jar $HUDSON_WAR > $HUDSON_LOG 2>&1 &
```

(using real values for those variables, of course), what exactly happens? I've been a software engineer for 10+ years but mostly in embedded, and web services are out of my domain. I don't think it makes a difference, but I'm running Hudson on RHEL 5. It's not using tomcat or apache; it's running as a standalone service. What files are accessed and why?

Here are the specifics of the failure: I downloaded a plugin and after it had finished downloading I stopped and then restarted hudson, as I've done many times before. This time, however, when I try to access the Hudson main page, I get

```
Error 404
Exception:
Stacktrace:
 (none)
```

I suspected a permissions issue since I noticed some of the things in HUDSON_HOME were owned by root, so I recursively chown and chgrp'd that directory to make hudson own it all. That has not fixed the problem. I tried restoring the previous hudson.war but got the same behavior. One thing I notice is that right after I start it, if I go to the web page, I see Hudson's "starting up" page, and then it switches to the Error 404. I tried starting Hudson with a different port number and got the same behavior. I have no problem accessing a web interface to source control on the same server.

Update: I still suspect a permissions issue. It's possible the last person to restart Hudson did so as root.

```
Update[2]: Excerpt from hudson.log:
[Winstone 2010/10/21 16:05:17] - Beginning extraction from war file
hudson home directory: /home/hudson
[Winstone 2010/10/21 16:05:17] - HTTP Listener started: port=8080
[Winstone 2010/10/21 16:05:17] - AJP13 Listener started: port=8009
Using one-time self-signed certificate
[Winstone 2010/10/21 16:05:17] - Error starting listener instance
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:516)
    at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:232)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:205)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:391)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at Main.main(Main.java:200)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun.security.x509.CertAndKeyGen
    at winstone.ssl.HttpsListener.<init>(HttpsListener.java:111)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.security.x509.CertAndKeyGen
    at java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.<init>(ClassNotFoundException.java:77)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:385)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:653)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:619)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: what is the content of the log file?

Answer (score 2):

I'm just guessing here, but you may not be running the right Java binary.

Often on Linux, the java binary in `/usr/bin` is a gcc Java implementation or an OpenJDK package. I've had trouble in the past with these Java packages just not working well enough. If you have the <strike>Sun</strike>Oracle JDK installed, it's probably in `/usr/java`. I suggest setting JAVA_HOME to `/usr/java/default` and making sure the right java runtime is being run when you start Hudson.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default
nohup $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar $HUDSON_WAR > $HUDSON_LOG 2>&1 &
```

Personally, I think it's easier to use the init script provided with Hudson to start and stop Hudson. The script uses a central configuration file and makes sure Hudson is run as the right user.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/hudson start
```

Also, check HUDSON_LOG and/or `/var/log/hudson/hudson.log` for errors. If it's an issue with the plugin that you recently installed, you can disable the plugin by moving aside the `[plugin]` folder and `[plugin].hpi` file in `HUDSON_HOME/plugins`

Comment: java -version tells me it's 1.6.0, though that is /usr/bin/java. To be sure, I made the path of the java binary Hudson has always used explicit in a command line invocation, but that didn't change anything.      Regarding the plugins, thank you for the suggestion, though that didn't work.  I'll update my question with an excerpt from hudson.log

Comment: To remove a plugin, you need to do delete the HPI _and_ delete the exploded hpi folder (same name as hpi).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Hudson troubleshooting is normally done through the Manage Hudson interface using a Groovy script.  Also, debug logging is most likely available.  Quote from the "how to add loggers" page:  "Tell us the symptom of your problem in the users list and we should be able to tell you where you need to look at. Also, this is really just a wrapper around the java.util.logging package, so if you program in Java, you might be able to guess what to look at."  The user list that they're talking about is a mailing list.

*How to add new/more loggers*:  http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Logging

*How to get onto the user list*:  http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Mailing+List

*Administration Details*:  http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Administering+Hudson

*Scripting*:  http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Hudson+Script+Console

*Some more scripting examples*:  http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HudsonHowToDebug

Comment: Thank you for these pointers. Hudson will now start, but it thinks it's a fresh installation, prompting me to create a job to get started. Do you know what it's looking for that it can't find, in order to get this page?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, this problem was caused by two issues:
1) Permissions were messed up. Since Hudson had previously been started as root, several of the files needed for operation became owned by root. I couldn't find a good synopsis of which hudson-related files ought to be owned by hudson and which as root and guessing wasn't working, so after making a backup, I re-installed Hudson.

2) Because I had been using the default hudson home of ".hudson" with a dot, but tried restarting with a specified HUDSON_HOME of /home/hudson (no dot), Hudson created a fresh home in /home/hudson and acted like it was a brand new installation. I had seen the HUDSON_HOME variable somewhere and thought it would be good to specify it in my startup script as /home/hudson, and thereby unwittingly changed the home used by Hudson. Once that was fixed, it's back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem after I upgraded from jdk 7 to jdk 8 and installed glassfish 4 on the same server box. I solved it by switching back to former jdk:

sudo alternatives --config java

There are 3 programs which provide 'java'.

### Selection    Command

- 1           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
- 2           /usr/java/latest/bin/java
  3           /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk7.45/bin/java

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number: 3